# Why don't toString and hasOwnProperty (etc) show up in for-in loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, foreach, hasownproperty

I was talking about hasOwnProperty with another developer and how you are supposed to use it in for-in loops in javascript and he had a good question.  When you do a for-in loop, why doesnt toString, hasOwnProperty, and other built in methods show up in the loop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure these methods have the internal *enumerable* attribute set to `false` but I cannot find any reference. Maybe because `Object.prototype` is marked this way. See http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.2.3

Comment: @Felix - that's exactly the answer.

Comment: @Felix, http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/.  Make that an answer.

Comment: can we utilize this enumerable attribute ourselves or is that internal only?

Comment: @Allen: In the newest version (ES 5) you can. And I have to revise my comment: It is not because of `Object.protoype`. If you add custom properties to it, they show up in the loop afaik.

Comment: @Felix, yes if you add to `Object.prototype` they show up in a for-in, however, if you redefine `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = "YES"`, it will not show up, at least not in IE<9, from my understanding, it should then show up in IE9 or greater or other browsers though.  This is discussed in that awesome post that hyperslug linked to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ECMAScript defines several properties for each property found on objects such as in prototypes. One of these is the `enumerable` property, and if it is set to `false`, then that property will be skipped.

You can actually manipulate these properties using the [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) function:

> This method allows precise addition to or modification of a property on an object. Normal property addition through assignment creates properties which show up during property enumeration (for...in loop), whose values may be changed, and which may be deleted. This method allows these extra details to be changed from their defaults.

Answer (score 4):

It is per specification

> A for...in loop does not iterate over
>   built-in properties. These include all
>   built-in methods of objects, such as
>   String's indexOf method or Object's
>   toString method. However, the loop
>   will iterate over all user-defined
>   properties (including any which
>   overwrite built-in properties).

From [Mozilla Developer Network page on for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

It is internally based on the enumerable attribute of these properties, as you can check in the [EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (search for "for-in", the "enumerable" attribute is described page 30)

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure these methods have the internal *[[Enumerable]]* attribute set to `false` but I cannot find anything where this is explicitly stated.

**Update:** Apparently, being non-enumerable is the default setting for properties defined in the specification (if not specified otherwise) (see table 7 in the link below).

You can find more information about these attributes in the specification: [Property attributes](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.6.1):

> If `true`, the property will be enumerated by a for-in enumeration (see [12.6.4](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.6.4)). Otherwise, the property is said to be non-enumerable.

Comment: Just download the ECMAScript PDF and search; there are preciously few HTML versions of the document and the ECMA does not maintain such a version themselves.

Comment: @Martijn: I had a look at it. But the specifiction of these methods that not state that this attribute is set to false. Maybe it is somewhere written in the text.

Comment: Section 8.6.1, tables 5 through to 7 (the latter defines the defaults).

Comment: @Martijn: Ah, ok then it is because it is the default value.... well, sometimes it is explicitly stated that the property is *not* enumerable, so this is a bit confusing.

Comment: That's the ECMA standards for you. :-) Ever tried to read the whole thing?

Comment: @Martijn: I started it, but somehow I got better things to do then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Built-in properties aren't enumerable therefore `toString` and `hasOwnProperty` aren't enumerable. In ECMAScript 3 every user defined method or property is enumerable. In ECMAScript 5 you can choose if method or property would be enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but here's an example of hasOwnProperty working from inside a for-in loop:

```
var i,o={some:"thing"};for(i in o)alert(o.hasOwnProperty("some"));
```

Comment: I'm not asking about how to use it, I'm saying its obviously a member of every objects prototype but it never shows up in a for-in loop.  Lepidosteus has the right answer.

Comment: np, its not a normal hasOwnProperty question :)